# rspec + rails_admin testing custom rails_admin action in /lib gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-admin

My `rspec` test were executing fine before I created a custom `rails_admin` action in `lib` folder.

Custom action for creating a Dashboard looks like this: `/lib/rails_admin.rb`

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Dashboard < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :root? do
          true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It gives the desired results i.e: new dashboard. 
But now when I run rspec test (any test) it gives following error:

> Bundler::GemRequireError:
>
> There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rails_admin'.
>
> Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant
>   RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base

Before running any test rspec loads all files from lib folder but can't find RailsAdmin for some reason.

To get rid of the error I tried to manually include rails_admin files

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Dashboard < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :root? do
          true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It doesn't fix the problem just moves the error to the next level and gives following error:

> Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',
>   **FILE**)
>
> NoMethodError:   undefined method `config' for RailsAdmin:Module
>    ./config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in`'

Where `rails_admin.rb` first line is simply:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
```

Why rspec isn't able to load the rails_admin gem correctly?

Comment: Do you have your lib path added to the rspec load path? If I recall, that's not done by default .

Comment: @BillyKimble lib isn't in rspec load path and if I am not wrong since rspec 3.x lib is automatically loaded (discussion on that issue https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1983). I can run rspec test by removing lib folder from LOAD_PATH but that's only temporary solution.

Comment: @Sharj have you found any solution for this ? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @JulesCorb didn't find a solution, but a temporary fix. I remove `lib/rails_admin.rb` file from loaded path so I can test everything else. Put `$LOAD_PATH.delete_if { |p| File.expand_path(p) == File.expand_path("./lib/rails_admin.rb") }` in `rails_helper.rb` before `configure`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no clue on why this works, I found a working solution :

instead of having `lib/rails_admin.rb`, I created a `config` subfolder and an `actions` subfolder in it, then placed my `rails_admin.rb` file inside.

I ended up with the following tree : `lib/config/actions/rails_admin.rb`. You also need to change the path of this file in your `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` :

In my case I had `require Rails.root.join('lib', 'rails_admin.rb')` and changed it to `require Rails.root.join('lib', 'config', 'actions', 'rails_admin.rb')`.

Then to run `bundle exec rspec` works as expected.